# Why the project show errors on referenced packages if I opened all the other necessary projects?

Tags: java, github, reference

I downloaded all the projects from git hub, opened all them in Netbeans, but when I try to build the main project, it doesn't work. The error message says that ALL the projects I referenced are missing or doesn't exist.
I'm not a software developer, I know only the basic but I want to debug a project.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you able to open/view this project using file explorer?